# HTML display variably long list of variably long items in columns

Tags: html, css

I have a variably long `<ul>` list of variably long items. I would like to display them in columns, as many columns as the width of the container allows, and without breaking the individual items into multiple lines. I am trying to do this with the CSS property `column-width`. The problem is that, since I don't know how long the items are (they are dynamically generated), I cannot set a fixed width for the columns, because if I do, the columns overlap when there is a long item, like so:

[image: Screenshot 1]

So what I would like is that the width of the columns adapts to the length of the items, like so:

[image: Screenshot 2]

Can this be done with CSS? If not, can it be done with JavaScript? (I do not know JavaScript, unfortunately.)

Here is the code that I currently have:

**HTML:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li>apple</li>
            <li>banana</li>
            <li>car pool</li>
            <li>dog</li>
            <li>egg</li>
            <li>ferry</li>
            <li>grasshopper</li>
            <li>house</li>
            <li>ice</li>
            <li>joy</li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
ul { column-width: 7em; }
li { white-space: nowrap; }
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I believe column-count can be useful. Sets the number of columns instead of their width. It requires media queries to reducing/increasing the count though.

Comment: @H.W.Sanden: I don't understand your suggestion, I'm sorry. In order to be able to set the number of columns, I would need, again, to know the length of the items in the list. How can I get that information with a media query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go!

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css" /> -->
  <style>
    ul {
      column-width: 7em;
    }

    li {
      white-space: nowrap;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <ul id="ul">
    <li>apple</li>
    <li>banana</li>
    <li>car</li>
    <li>dog</li>
    <li>egg</li>
    <li>fig tree plantation fig tree</li>
    <li>garden</li>
    <li>house</li>
    <li>ice</li>
    <li>joy</li>
    <li>egg</li>
    <li>fig tree plantation fig tree</li>
    <li>garden</li>
    <li>house</li>
    <li>ice</li>
    <li>joy</li>
  </ul>
  <script>
    let listItems = document.querySelectorAll("#ul > li");  // Selecting all li tags.
    let lengthList = [];                                    // Holding an empty array to store the biggest text length

    listItems.forEach((el, index) => {                      // Filling the array with all text lengths
      lengthList[index] = el.innerHTML.length;  
    })

    let biggestLength = Math.max(...lengthList);            // Finding the biggest text length available

    let list = document.querySelector("#ul");               // Selecting the ul tag to apply some style on it
    list.style.columnWidth = `${biggestLength * 10}px`;     // Finally applied the column-width css prop dynamically.

  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

It will set the `column-width` dynamically after checking the text length available.
Hope this helps, adjust the width accordingly inside `script` tag (the last line)

Comment: That works, thank you very much! So I take it that there is no way to do this with CSS alone?

Comment: No, for sure there will be a way to do it with css as well, however I don't have any mentos in my pocket. haha

Comment: Well, I tried to find a CSS-only solution for some time, but didn't succeed... I have a further question about your solution: If I want to apply this solution several times on my page, for several lists, can I -- rather than copy the code each time -- formulate the code as a function, put this function in the <head> section and then call the function every time that I need it?

Comment: Here is the slightly modified [function](https://jsfiddle.net/jawh09t5/2/). Only `ul` selector need to be passed as an argument, rest it will select all the `li` tags inside that `ul` tag, verify the biggest text length and set the width accordingly.

Comment: The function works perfectly, thank you very much! I have one more question about how to call this function. I currently call it with `<script>setDynamicWidth("#ul_1");</script>` after the `<ul>` element. I am wondering whether it can also be called from within the `<ul>` tag, i.e., with something like `onload="setDynamicWidth('#ul_1')"` (which doesn't work).

Comment: Function can be called using `onload` attribute on `ul` tag but again that will be useless because function gets executed right after the `ul` tag loaded successfully no matter the `li` tag is loaded inside `ul` or not.  It's a best practice to use the `script` tag at the end.

Comment: However if there is any such requirements to execute the function using `onload` attribute, use can use setTimeout() function available in js.  This function takes two arguments:1st another function which need to be executed and second: delay in milliseconds.  This will delay the execution by few milliseconds so that `li` tags also present for the function to use.